# Storybook internal server

Tags: vuejs3, storybook, vite

I am using Storybook + Vu3 + Vite. Now, It is throwing me an error " [vite] Internal server error: No files matching '/virtual:/@storybook/builder-vite/vite-app.js' were found."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CFB2.png)

Comment: This probably means there was a problem building the app.  Do you get any error messages in the terminal where you started up storybook?